# Как найти соседний селектор в css?

Tags: css

Я знаю, что при коде вида `.class1 + .class2` заданые стили применятся к классу `class2`, который следует сразу после `class1`.
Но как мне задать стили конкретно классу1, после которого есть `class2`?

Comment: `.class1:first-child` или `.class0 + .class1`

Comment: @webDev_ 1) и как ему поможет first-child? Он применится даже если рядом никого не будет. 2)поменять порядок нельзя т.к. тогда не будет выделения. С сайта learn.javascript.ru: "div + p – первый правый сосед: p на том же уровне вложенности, который идёт сразу после div (если есть)."

Comment: Обратного селектора в CSS нет, потому в общем виде такой запрос можно решить только через яваскрипт.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko наверно ты прав, т.к. я тоже не нашел ничего толкового в доках по css. Но вопрос жутко интересный и мб кто-то предложит нестандартное решение) мб через  блок родителя как то извратиться можно ?

Comment: в js я то проверю, если .next('') равно чему-то, то такие стили прописать, а если нет то такие, но у меня именно решение через css волнует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку обратного селектора, вроде `.class1 - .class2` в CSS не существует, какой-нибудь частный случай можно решить селектором `+` или `~`, назначением `display: flex` родителю и установкой `order` потомкам. Разметка при этом должна исходить из того, что «предыдущий» элемент должен располагаться ниже. Альтернативой свойству `order` может быть свойство `flex-direction: row-reverse`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
}

.class2 {
  order: 1
}

.class3 {
  order: 2
}

.next ~ .prev {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class="child class3">class3</div>
  <div class="child next class2">class2</div>
  <div class="child prev class1">class1</div>
</div>
```